# Proof on Borel subsets of continous function space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $M$ be separable metric space and $C(M)$ a space of continuous functions on $M$ endowed with the supremum norm. For $B(C(M))$ denoting the Borel subsets of $C(M)$, prove that $B(C(M)) = \sigma(\{ f \in C(M): f(t) \in (a, b] \}: t \in M, -\infty \leq a \leq b \leq \infty) $

Comment: What if there is an unbounded function in $C(M)$ as e.g. $M = \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x$ ? The supremum norm is undefined then.

Comment: "a space of continuous functions on $M$ endowed with the supremum norm."

Comment: The supremum norm means $\displaystyle \sup_{x \in M} |f(x)|$ which is undefined if $f$ is unbounded. So you can't endow $C(M)$ with the supremum norm.

Comment: $M$ should be compact.